# Convolution network configuration problem

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to get accuracy information from a **convolutional net**.
If I choose **classification** I get an output like this:

```
epoch train loss valid loss train/val valid acc dur

  1       0.50873       0.60935      0.83488      0.79269  11.24s
  2       0.50304       0.58649      0.85771      0.79269  11.91s
  3       0.49532       0.57172      0.86637      0.79269  11.89s
  4       0.49352       0.55105      0.89560      0.79269  11.92s
  5       0.49049       0.53669      0.91392      0.79269  11.75s
  6       0.48861       0.52467      0.93127      0.79269  11.64s
```

And both loss (train,valid) tends to converge to **`0.5`**.

If I chose `regression` it works fine (I guess). 
At the regression task the train and valid losses were like `0.18, 0.16`.

I made a bit workaround and I found the the net returns a matrix of values as results as follows:

```
[[0.805, 0.802],
 [0.802, 0.798],
 [0.800, 0.804],
 [0.798, 0.802],
.
.
.
 [0.803, 0.805]]
```

So, as I think the softmax calculates its response base of these values and gives me always `"1"` as value, that's why the constant accuracy value. And, yes the returned class is always `"1"`.
It is probably a basic fault of me, but I can't figure out, what can be the problem.

My network:

```
net = NeuralNet(
    layers=[
        ('input', layers.InputLayer),

        ('conv1', Conv2DLayer),
        ('pool1', MaxPool2DLayer),
        ('dropout1', layers.DropoutLayer),

        ('conv2', Conv2DLayer),
        ('pool2', MaxPool2DLayer),
        ('dropout2', layers.DropoutLayer),

        ('conv3', Conv2DLayer),
        ('pool3', MaxPool2DLayer),
        ('dropout3', layers.DropoutLayer),

        ('conv4', Conv2DLayer),
        ('pool4', MaxPool2DLayer),
        ('dropout4', layers.DropoutLayer),

        ('hidden1', layers.DenseLayer),
        ('dropout5', layers.DropoutLayer),

        ('hidden2', layers.DenseLayer),
        ('output', layers.DenseLayer),
        ],

#### start network configuration ##############################################

    input_shape=(None,3,256,256),

    conv1_num_filters=16, conv1_filter_size=(8, 8), 
    conv1_stride=4, conv1_pad=1, 
    conv1_nonlinearity = nonlinearities.leaky_rectify,
    pool1_pool_size=(3, 3), pool1_stride=2,
    dropout1_p=0.2,

    conv2_num_filters=32, conv2_filter_size=(4, 4), 
    conv2_stride=1, conv2_pad=1, 
    conv2_nonlinearity = nonlinearities.leaky_rectify,
    pool2_pool_size=(3, 3), pool2_stride=2,
    dropout2_p=0.3,

    conv3_num_filters=64, conv3_filter_size=(3, 3), 
    conv3_stride=1, conv3_pad=1, 
    conv3_nonlinearity = nonlinearities.leaky_rectify,
    pool3_pool_size=(3, 3), pool3_stride=2,
    dropout3_p=0.4,

    conv4_num_filters=64, conv4_filter_size=(3, 3), 
    conv4_stride=1, conv4_pad=1, 
    conv4_nonlinearity = nonlinearities.leaky_rectify,
    pool4_pool_size=(3, 3), pool4_stride=2,
    dropout4_p=0.5,

    hidden1_num_units=256, 
    dropout5_p=0.5,
    hidden2_num_units=128, 

    output_num_units=2, output_nonlinearity = nonlinearities.softmax,

#### end network configuration ################################################

    update=nesterov_momentum,
    update_learning_rate=theano.shared(float32(0.01)),
    update_momentum=theano.shared(float32(0.7)),

    batch_iterator_train=BatchIterator__RP(batch_size=batch_size),
    batch_iterator_test=BatchIterator__RP(batch_size=batch_size),

    regression=regression,
    on_epoch_finished=[
        AdjustVariable('update_learning_rate', start=0.001, stop=0.0001),
        AdjustVariable('update_momentum', start=0.7, stop=0.999),
        EarlyStopping(patience=100),
        ],
    max_epochs=100,
    verbose=1,
    )
```

Thank you in advance.
George